# How to set VSCode typescript format for if statement

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to config the VSCode format to not set a new line after && in if statement

I'm trying to search after some new line functions at the settings.json

this what happened today after format 
[image]

I'm trying to set the format do this 
[image: [expect after format](https://imgur.com/jYgGxhU)]

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, go to `Settings > Text Editor > Word Wrap`, and turn it off.

Alternatively, go to `Settings > Text Editor > Word Wrap Column`, and increase the column in which words will wrap (default is 80 I believe).